# How to login in Moodle using PHP Application using OK Tech Web services?

Tags: php, moodle

I want to login in Moodle using PHP Application using `login()` function of OK Tech Web services.

When I did login on my Application, in Login function I write following code for login in Moodle of OK Tech Web Services.

I have tried two methods:

1 -

```
            $postdata = http_build_query(
                array(
                    'username' => 'XXXXXX',
                    'password' => 'XXXXXX',
                    'wsfunction' => 'login',
                    'wsformatout' => 'dump'
                )
            );

            $opts = array('http' =>
                array(
                    'method'  => 'POST',
                    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'content' => $postdata
                )
            );
            $context  = stream_context_create($opts);

            $result = file_get_contents('http://mymoodleserver/wspp/service_pp2.php', false, $context);
```

and second method

```
$xml_user =  simplexml_load_file('http://mymoodleserver/wspp/service_pp2.php?username=XXXXXX&password=XXXXXX&wsfunction=login&wsformatout=dump');
```

This way I did code and use the function.

Now please check this.

Comment: Flukey, I have tried OK Tech Web services url http://moodleserverURL/wspp/service_pp2.php?username=XXXXX&password=XXXXX&wsfunction=login&wsformatout=dump

Comment: I did use this URL (http://moodleserverURL/wspp/service_pp2.php?username=XXXXX&password=XXXXX&wsfunction=login&wsformatout=dump) when I loggin in my APplication using file_get_contents and also simplexml_load_file.. but i did not session in moodle..

Comment: your link doesnt work can you show your code

Comment: I can paste code but i can not disclose my server to anybody as it is confidential..

Comment: So how can we help if we can't see any code? How is it confidential if it's generic 'OK Tech Web Services code?' Just don't post any credentials...

Comment: I have post the code in question.. Please see this..

Comment: This can be closed as Unclear or for not having a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use login function of Moodle instead of using OK Tech Web services.